# Android Socket Stuck every 20 seconds

Tags: android, c, sockets, tcp

I am using a TCP socket connection in an action game, we use lockstep synchronization, client will receive 20 - 40 packets per second. It works fine when the game is running on a PC but when running on Android devices, the socket will get stuck every 20 seconds

[Server sends 5 packets per second](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r0y5A.png)

I have tried to use Unity3D's C# socket, Android Java socket and Android native C socket and blocking/non-blocking mode, small/large (1byte/100byte) data per packet, less/more (5/50) packets per second, use single thread/main thread, on multiple Android devices, all of them have the same issue.

PS: It seems the 20 second duration is based on devices, not my app or connection; that means if last stuck happens at 1:00:00, the next stuck will happen at 1:00:20, even if we reconnect or restart the app.

Android native C code:

```
    extern "C" JNIEXPORT int JNICALL
Java_com_example_ymoon_sockettest_MainActivity_connect(JNIEnv *env, jobject /* this */)
{
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "CSocket", "Connecting...");

    int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sock < 0) return -1;

    struct sockaddr_in server;
    memset(&server, 0, sizeof(server));

    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port   = htons(12350);
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.3.66");

    if (connect(sock, (struct sockaddr*)&server, sizeof(server)) < 0)
    {
        close(sock);
        return -2;
    }

    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "CSocket", "Connected");

    char buf[100];

    int t = -1;
    int received = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        int count = recv(sock, &buf, 100, 0);
        if (count < 1) break;

        received += count;

        struct timeval tv;
        gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);

        int m = tv.tv_sec * 1000 + tv.tv_usec / 1000;
        int diff = m - t;
        t = m;
        std::string p = t < 0 ? "" : diff < 50 ? "-" : diff < 100 ? "-|" : diff < 150 ? "--|" :
            diff < 250 ? "---|" :  diff < 500 ? "----|" : diff < 1000 ? "-----|" : "------|";
        __android_log_print(diff > 500 ? ANDROID_LOG_ERROR : ANDROID_LOG_INFO,
                            "CSocket", "%i | %s %i", received, p.c_str(), diff);
    }

    close(sock);

    return 0;
}
```

Am I doing something wrong ?
It is my first time to ask a question on stackoverflow, sorry for my bad English, any help or suggestion is appreciated, thanks.

**Edit: add server code, i rewrite a simple tcp server to test (Window platform)**

```
 int main()
{

    addrinfo conf, *add = nullptr;
    memset(&conf, 0, sizeof(conf));

    conf.ai_flags    = AI_PASSIVE;
    conf.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    conf.ai_family   = AF_INET;

    if (getaddrinfo(nullptr, "12350", &conf, &add)) return 0;

    SOCKET serverSock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    char opt = 1;
    if (setsockopt(serverSock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &opt, sizeof(opt)) == -1 ||
        setsockopt(serverSock, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, &opt, sizeof(opt)) == -1 ||
        bind(serverSock, add->ai_addr, add->ai_addrlen) == -1 ||
        listen(serverSock, 0) == -1)
    {
        close(serverSock);
        return 0;
    }

    printf("Listening....\n");

    sockaddr_storage incoming_addr;

    int size = sizeof(incoming_addr);
    SOCKET clientSock = accept(serverSock, (sockaddr*)&incoming_addr, &size);

    printf("Client connected\n");

    char buf[1] = { 0 };
    int sendCount = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        time_t t = time(nullptr);
        tm *lt = localtime(&t);
        printf("%02d:%02d:%02d Send to client %i\n", lt->tm_hour, lt->tm_min, lt->tm_sec, ++sendCount);

        if (send(clientSock, buf, 1, 0) < 1) break;
        Sleep(200);
    }

    close(serverSock);

    return 0;
}
```

**Edit: Add WireShark capture image:**
[Wireshark shot when stuck happen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5hOkE.png)

Comment: int count = recv(sock, &buf[0], 1024, 0); should be 
int count = recv(sock, &buf, 100, 0);

Comment: yeah, that is a mistake, I forgot to change it, but it is not the reason to case this promblem

Comment: Can you post server code also if possible

Comment: Server code added

Comment: Does it happen on linux pc? I'm trying but problem is not seen.

Comment: I have not test client side on Linux yet, but test server side on both Windows and Linux, I will try it later...this is really strange....

Comment: It is been running for 4 hours now, no issue.

Comment: Thanks for your patience and help, I will try it on Linux and different network environment tomorrow

Comment: the functions:  `recv()` and `send()` return a `ssize_t`, not a `int`.

Comment: the 'server' and the 'client' are ignoring each other.  Strongly suggest the code be modified so they run in 'lock step'  Then the consistent drift between them will not cause problems

Comment: regarding: `client will receive 20 - 40 packets per second.`  the posted code is only passing 5 packets per second,  Please post the actual code that is giving the problem

Comment: No matter how many packets client receive per second, run in lockstep mode or not, they both have the same issue. recv() and send() return size_t, but I think it is fine to cast them to int, does this cast cause other problem ?

Comment: I have test it (code posted here) in my home, and another WIFI environment, it worked fine. The only difference is the WIFI environment, so I think maybe our company WIFI network settings cause this issue. @kiran Biradar Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have test it (code posted here) in my home, and another WIFI environment, it worked fine. The only difference is the WIFI environment, so I think maybe our company WIFI network settings cause this issue.